# Schengen visa will expire next month

Tags: visa, germany, working-visas, schengen

I am working here in Germany I have a valid Working contract but my Multiple Entry Schengen Visa will expire next month.

What should I do? I hope you can help me. and if there is a form or office that I can contact please provide me.

Comment: Why do you think you should do anything? Are you planning on traveling soon? Do you have any residence permit in Germany that may or may not be expiring?

Comment: "Schengen visa" typically refers to a type C short-stay visa.  These visas usually do not authorize employment.  Is the expiring visa a type C or type D visa?  If it is a type C visa, what sort of work authorization do you have?

Comment: @littleadv Travel is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @Relaxed I might have mixed some terms up, but isn't visa a document used for border crossing?

Comment: @littleadv That's exactly how it works in the US, not quite in the EU. In EU law, a visa is just a type of residence “title“, covering both border crossing and status while in-country (title is the French or German word, English-language terminology is a tad confusing). If you have a proper residence permit, you do not need a visa to cross the border but if your visa expires, it's illegal to stay longer without another residence title. So it's perfectly reasonable to ask what should I do about the expiration of my visa, irrespective of any travel plan, which wouldn't be the case in the US.

Comment: @Relaxed so there's no concept in EU similar to the US I-94 or EAD or similar things other countries have? Sorry, never needed a EU visa in my life (I know, I'm lucky)

Comment: @littleadv Nothing like the I-94, no. Border guards have absolutely no role in deciding the length of your stay, they can only decide whether you may enter or not. Duration of stay is entirely controlled by the visa you got (or the visa exemption rules if your citizenship allows for a visa-free short stay). It should change soon but your entry may not even be recorded anywhere, the only thing that's mandatory is stamping your passport. Together with the visa, it's enough for law enforcement to determine if your presence is still legal.

Comment: @Relaxed that is so weird....

Comment: @littleadv The US system felt equally weird to me when I discovered it. There are other benefits but in the context of the Schengen area, it's hard to imagine how it could work differently. When you present yourself to the border, the length of stay that's appropriate for your purpose and circumstances has already been evaluated by the relevant consular authorities, who have a lot more time and information to do it. If it hadn't, it would potentially be left to the discretion of a border guard *from another country* than your main destination and that would definitely be weirder.

Comment: @Relaxed but work authorization is a matter of national law, is it not?  I recall hearing long ago (about France, if I recall correctly, but maybe it was Germany or another country) that short-term work authorization was available separate from and in addition to a type C visa (or visa-free stay).  If that is true then this would be similar to a US EAD (which in any event is not formal evidence of permission to be in the US, although it does more or less imply such permission).

Comment: @phoog Yes, correct, I am not that familiar with the EAD, which is why I kind of dodged that question but it does sound similar. But even if you have a separate work authorisation, you still need a visa or residence permit for the whole duration of your stay. In practice, you would typically apply for the authorisation before the visa, as it's listed as a required document if you want a short-stay visa for work purposes.

Comment: @Relaxed but consider this: I spent 89 days in Schengen area, went to the UK for a day, and now am coming back. The border agent knows that I cannot stay the full 90 days again, right? I'm only allowed to stay 90 days in 180 period, so I'm only allowed to stay 1 day. How would this be enforced then? Based on what you're describing - it cannot be enforced at all. Even in the UK, while they still were part of the EU (but not Schengen), the stamp at the airport explicitly mentioned for how long I can stay. In fact in most countries I've been to that's the case, except Schengen.

Comment: @phoog the EAD card is in fact an evidence of permission to be in the US, and with a special annotation can even be used instead of a visa for admission purposes.

Comment: @littleadv "How would this be enforced then?": You have two stamps in your passport indicating 89 days of presence.  You have another stamp in your passport indicating that you entered a day or two after your previous departure.  It's quite clear that you are illegally present as of the beginning of the day after your second arrival, because it's your 91st day.  You will get caught when you leave.  That's how it's supposed to work, at least; in practice the checking of stamps is frequently insufficiently attentive.

Comment: @phoog what if I use different passports? What if I lose my passport with the stamp and get a temporary document from the consulate? You can't possibly just rely on a piece of paper, can you?

Comment: @littleadv "what if...?": then you're not likely to get caught.  If you lose your passport while you're in the Schengen area then you can be asked to show other evidence to establish that you didn't overstay.  The Schengen area has been relying on pieces of paper for decades.  That will end soon with the implementation of the entry/exit system, which will record border crossings by short-stay visitors in a database.

Comment: @littleadv if by "special annotation" you mean "serves as I-512 Advance Parole" then that's not a simple EAD but a combination EAD/AP card.  An EAD that is not also AP is not evidence of permission to be in the US; anyone who has such a card will have some other document showing permission to be in the US.

Comment: @littleadv As phoog explained, that's what stamps are for but it's not working very well and the EU is currently rolling out a system to register [entries and exits](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/policies/schengen-borders-and-visa/smart-borders/entry-exit-system_en). But it will not change any of the principles I detailed: border guards still won't have any discretion regarding the duration of stay and visitors will need a visa covering their whole stay, not only the date of entry.

Comment: Note that law enforcement and policy makers in the EU are not terribly concerned about all that. People going back and forth and staying a little longer is not a real problem. Right now they are more concerned about refugees (who cannot easily be sent back, never mind the duration of their stay), citizens returning from Syria (who wouldn't be caught by a system tracking visa holders), and people who enter legally and then try to stay longer than allowed (and if you are in this situation, you know to avoid the border).

Comment: @littleadv Indeed, British stamps mention the duration because border guards there legally decide  how long you can stay (they grant you a leave to enter). But you can see how this is completely unrelated to the questions we were discussing before: This system has existed for a long time and originally relied on pieces of paper. It's actually even more difficult to enforce than the Schengen system because you need to track some additional info (the duration granted when you entered).

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do?

You need to secure another visa or some sort of residence permit. As explained in @phoog's earlier comment, your current situation is a little unclear but the general principle is simple. In Germany and the rest of the EU, ignoring some edge cases (*Duldung*, refugees…), third-country citizens require an residence permit (or *Aufenthaltstitel*). A visa is a type of *Aufenthaltstitel* but if yours is expiring, you would in any case need another one.

That said, before rushing to apply for one, I would double-check what your current status is. A multiple-entry Schengen visa is typically a short-stay visa that does not in itself gives you the right to work. Unless you actually had another type of visa or some sort of separate work authorisation, starting to work would have been illegal and both you and your employer could get in trouble for that. If that's the case, it would seem urgent to hire a lawyer before approaching the authorities.